# How to build an Android project with Ninja?

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk, ninja

I have an Android project with a `app/src/CMakeLists.txt` file like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library( # Specifies the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )
```

I also have a `app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp` file in my project.

When I run `ninja` in a terminal I get this error

```
ninja: error: loading 'build.ninja': No such file or directory
```

I'm not familiar with the NDK and I'm trying to run the project with [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) but I'm not able to find any clear documentation or example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android NDK uses CMake to build projects, but instead of run `ninja` separately, you should run below gradle command to trigger your NDK project build.

```
./gradlew externalNativeBuild
```

Internally, CMake will use the ninja build system to compile and link the C/C++ sources for your apps.

Comment: Here is my personal NDK example, hope it is helpful for your case: https://github.com/russell-shizhen/JniExample

Comment: Thank you shizhen, yes it is!